# Call ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings in .net framewok from .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

Context: I'm currently trying to determine if it'd be possible for my company to create a new web project using the `.net-core-2.0` framework that calls some shared class libraries running on `.net-framework-4.5` without having to alter them at all.

---

- I have a `.net framework 4.5` shared class library that contains a `Foo` method
- The `Foo` method makes a call to `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`
- In my `.net-core-2.0` web app's controller I call `SharedLibrary.Foo()`
- The `ConfigurationManager` returns `null`

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    // Real values replaced with **** for security reasons, of course :-)
    "ConnectionStringSecurehSQL": "Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;user=****;password=****;Connect Timeout=100000"
  }
}
```

The call to `ConfigurationManager`

```
var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSecurehSQL"];
```

I expected to obtain a connexion string, not a `null` value. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible ? If it is what am I doing wrong ?